# unable to upload an image using gd library php

Tags: php, html, gd

this php file receives data from a html file where an user uploads an image from his computer, as soon as the update button is clicked this php page returns an error in which it is stated that no such file or directory exists

```html
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);?>
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'pippo', 'pluto') or 
    die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.');
mysql_select_db('moviesite', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

// current images folder
$dir ='image_php/images';

// make sure the upload succeeded
if ($_FILES['uploadfile']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
 switch ($_FILES['uploadfile']['error']) {
 case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
     die('The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive' .
      'in php.ini');
  break;
 case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
     die('The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that ' .
      'was specified in the HTML form.');
  break;
 case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
     die('The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.');
  break;
 case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
     die('No file was uploaded');
  break;
 case ULOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
     die('The server is missing a temporary folder');
  break;
 case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
     die('The Server failed to write the uploaded file to disk');
  break;
 case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
     die('File upload stopped by extension.');
  break;
 }
}

// retrieve data from created image
$image_caption = $_POST['caption'];
$image_username = $_POST['username'];
$image_date = date('Y-m-d');
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) =
    getimagesize($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']);

// make sure the uploaded file is a supported image
switch ($type) {
case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
     $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']) or 
      die('The file you uploaded was not a supported filetype');
 $ext = '.gif';
 break;
case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']) or 
     die('The file you uploaded was not a supported filetype');
 $ext = '.jpg';
 break;
case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
   $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']) or 
        die('THe file you uploaded was not a supported filetype');
   $ext = '.png';
   break;
default:
    die('The file you uploaded was not a supported filetype');
}

//insert information into image table 
$query = 'INSERT INTO images
    (image_caption, image_username, image_date)
VALUES
    ("' . $image_caption . '", "' . $image_username . '", "' . $image_date .
  '")';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

//retrieve image value
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();

// use id as image name
//per assicurarsi che l'immagine non sovrascriva altre immagini esistenti
$imagename = $last_id . $ext;

// update image table adding the image final name
$query = 'UPDATE images
    SET image_filename = "' . $imagename . '"
    WHERE image_id = ' . $last_id;
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));

// save image
switch ($type) {
case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
    imagegif($image, $dir . '/' . $imagename);
 break;
case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
    imagejpeg($image, $dir . '/' . $imagename, 100);
 break;
case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
    imagepng($image, $dir . '/' . $imagename);
 break;
}
imagedestroy($image);
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Here is your pic!</title>
  </head>
 <body>
   <h1>So how does it feel to be famous?</h1>
   <p>Here is the picture you just uploaded to our servers:</p>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $imagename; ?>" style="float:left;">
 <table>
 <tr><td>Image Saved as: </td><td><?php echo $imagename; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Image Type: </td><td><?php echo $ext; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Height: </td><td><?php echo $height; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Width: </td><td><?php echo $width; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Upload Date: </td><td><?php echo $image_date; ?></td></tr>
   </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

this is the error that the page returns:

Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open 'image_php/images/9.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/image_php/check_image.php on line 98

the form which allows to upload images

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload your pic to our site!</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
td {vertical-align: top;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="check_image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td>Your Username</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
   </tr>
   <td>Upload Image*</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="uploadfile" /></td>
   </tr><tr>
   <td colspan="2">
    <small><em>* Acceptable image formats include: GIF, JPG/JPEG and PNG.
 </em></small>
   </td>
   </tr><tr>
   <td>Image Caption<br/>
   </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="caption" /></td>
   </tr><tr>
   <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a valid enctype is required when dealing with files, are you not using one?

Comment: yes I am using a valid enctype in the html file which allows the image uploading

Comment: take it up with the answer given below then

Comment: make sure the folder you wish to write to, ***can*** be written to. Check permissions. Seems the most likely issue/solution here; that said about the warning.

Comment: so, where are we at here?

Comment: @Fred-ii- what do you mean?

Comment: did you check all folders' permissions and whether you can write to them? or has this been solved already?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have set php.ini to 0777 and also the www subfolder of var has been set to 0777 but seemingly the issue hasn't been fixed yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PHP manual here:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

> Files will, by default, be stored in the server's default temporary directory unless another location has been given with the upload_tmp_dir directive in php.ini. The server's default directory can be changed by setting the environment variable TMPDIR in the environment in which PHP runs. Setting it using putenv() from within a PHP script will not work. This environment variable can also be used to make sure that other operations are working on uploaded files, as well.

Probably your HTTP server hasn't write permission for temp dir or your php.ini has a temp dir configured for a dir where it hasn't write permission.
Check them.

Comment: should I create a temp folder then?

Comment: No. You should check your php.ini and see which temp dir is setted there. Then you check if your server user has write permissions to this dir.

Comment: i am using a web server which is set to a development environment a kind of mirror server that I have created it is not a production server

Comment: yes, even better. Check yor php.ini for a line containing upload_tmp_dir. If it's enabled this is the dir you have to check the permissions. If it's disabled then in system default. In most linux distribution this would be /tmp. Your http server user, if it's a default configuration should be www-data. So considering a default configuration you should check if www-data has write permissions on /tmp.

Comment: i am checking php.ini in the line you said but i cannot state whether or not it is disabled

Comment: php.ini permissions set to 0777 but nothing changed

Comment: I didn't understand. Did you fix it ?

Comment: well then tell us what is happening now, so we can help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392734/unable-to-set-permissions-to-upload-images-using-php-gd-library check this link out there is a similar question I've asked today