# unable to set permissions to upload images using php gd library

Tags: php, html, apache

This is a similar question I asked some days ago here you can find all of the source code you might need
[unable to upload an image using gd library php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352700/unable-to-upload-an-image-using-gd-library-php/30352891?noredirect=1#comment48805182_30352891)

in my php.ini I've updated `upload_tmp_dir` writing `upload_tmp_dir = /tmp` 
and `open_base_dir` to `open_base_dir = /tmp`

Anyways whenever I try to upload a file error reporting returns this bug:

> Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open 'image_php/images/18.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/image_php/check_image.php on line 98

As a matter of fact I am still unaware whether or not it is a problem of permission but I do believe it is and I am unable to upload images

here is the source code of the php which handles the submission of the file
this should be enought anyway this file comes after an html form where the user does upload the image choosing from his/her local folder based on his/her pc

```html
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);?>
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'goofy', 'donald') or 
    die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.');
mysql_select_db('moviesite', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

// cambiare questo percorso in modo che corrisponda a quello della cartella
// images in uso
$dir ='image_php/images';

// si assicura che il caricamento sia avvenuto correttamente
if ($_FILES['uploadfile']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
 switch ($_FILES['uploadfile']['error']) {
 case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
     die('The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive' .
      'in php.ini');
  break;
 case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
     die('The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that ' .
      'was specified in the HTML form.');
  break;
 case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
     die('The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.');
  break;
 case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
     die('No file was uploaded');
  break;
 case ULOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
     die('The server is missing a temporary folder');
  break;
 case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
     die('The Server failed to write the uploaded file to disk');
  break;
 case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
     die('File upload stopped by extension.');
  break;
 }
}

$image_file = tempnam($dir,"upload");
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $image_file)!=true) { die("Can't move uploaded file!"); }

// recupera le informazioni sull'immagine appena caricata
$image_caption = $_POST['caption'];
$image_username = $_POST['username'];
$image_date = date('Y-m-d');
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) =
    getimagesize($image_file);

// si assicura che il file caricato sia effettivamente un tipo di immagine
// supportato
switch ($type) {
case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
     $image = imagecreatefromgif($image_file) or 
      die('The file you uploaded was not a supported filetype');
 $ext = '.gif';
 break;
case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_file) or 
     die('The file you uploaded was not a supported filetype');
 $ext = '.jpg';
 break;
case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
   $image = imagecreatefrompng($image_file) or 
        die('THe file you uploaded was not a supported filetype');
   $ext = '.png';
   break;
default:
    die('The file you uploaded was not a supported filetype');
}

// inserisce nella tabella images le informazioni
$query = 'INSERT INTO images
    (image_caption, image_username, image_date)
VALUES
    ("' . $image_caption . '", "' . $image_username . '", "' . $image_date .
  '")';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

//recupera il valore image_id che MYSQL ha generatp automaticamente quando
// abbiamo inserito le informazioni sull'immagine della tabella
// il nuovo record
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();

// dato che id è univoco lo si può utilizzare anche come nome dell'immagine
//per assicurarsi che l'immagine non sovrascriva altre immagini esistenti
$imagename = $last_id . $ext;

// aggiorna la tabella images col nome finale dell'immagine
$query = 'UPDATE images
    SET image_filename = "' . $imagename . '"
    WHERE image_id = ' . $last_id;
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));

// salva l'immagine della sua destinazione finale
switch ($type) {
case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
    imagegif($image, $dir . '/' . $imagename);
 break;
case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
    imagejpeg($image, $dir . '/' . $imagename, 100);
 break;
case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
    imagepng($image, $dir . '/' . $imagename);
 break;
}
imagedestroy($image);
unlink($image_file);
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Here is your pic!</title>
  </head>
 <body>
   <h1>So how does it feel to be famous?</h1>
   <p>Here is the picture you just uploaded to our servers:</p>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $imagename; ?>" style="float:left;">
 <table>
 <tr><td>Image Saved as: </td><td><?php echo $imagename; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Image Type: </td><td><?php echo $ext; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Height: </td><td><?php echo $height; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Width: </td><td><?php echo $width; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Upload Date: </td><td><?php echo $image_date; ?></td></tr>
   </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I added the if condition into the code as suggested
but still we get back from where we started from: the page works I have every parameters I need but the image cannot be loaded

Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open 'image_php/images/20.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/image_php/check_image.php on line 101

Comment: Show us your code where you move the uploaded file to `image_php/images/18.jpg`. Your warning is not upload-related.

Comment: @umka I've just updated my question check it out

Comment: You have to [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) before open it.

Comment: @umka could you please provide me an answer dude?

Comment: See here
[PHP Upload file][1]


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @Livingstone what should I exactly do? I'm a kind of php beginner so please could you provide me an answer?

Comment: @umka have you been able to find a kind of solution?

Comment: Please do not **[cross-post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/284676/22815)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add right before `// retrieve image data`:

```
$image_file = tempnam($dir,"upload");
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $image_file);
```

Replace in further code all occurrences of `$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']` to `$image_file`

And after `imagedestroy()` add:

```
unlink($image_file);
```

Comment: I suspect, the script has no access to uploaded file. 

`if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $image_file)!=true) { die("Can't move uploaded file!"); }`

Comment: where do I have to add this? do I replace the existing lines you suggested me?

Comment: Yes, it's just an update for `move_uploaded_file` function to process the error.

Comment: I've replaced the existing move_upload part with the new one but nothing has changed maybe the script can't access the uploaded file

Comment: the question has been edited for the hundredth time but still nothing has changed and I can't find a solution to fix this bug

Comment: Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open 'image_php/images/22.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/image_php/check_image.php on line 101

Comment: This mean that the file has been successfully uploaded and processed, but can't be saved to the target location at the last stage. If you have enough permissions to write to "image_php/images/" directory, I have no idea, what it could be :(

Comment: so should image_php/images/ directory be rewritable? if so that folder is already rewritable

Comment: What is the file permissions for image_php/images/ ? please give us a ls -l of this dir. Also from the above dirs, like /var/www/html/php/, /var/www/html/, /var/www/html/, /var/www/ and /var. It's probably one of this dirs who has some permission that is blocking the write.